# SSMS 2012 - IntelliSense Complete Word

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I use SSMS 2012 with IntelliSense and it is usually fine. However, yesterday, the "complete word" function has turned itself on and is forcing my code to change according to what it wants.

For example, if I'm writing a multi table script and I know my first table will have an alias of "a", I will start by writing

Select a.*

But now, as soon as I hit the full stop button, the a changes to ABS

Select ABS.*

I like having IntelliSense on as I do use it, but I am not used to it overwriting what I type. I can't see any options to change this in the IntelliSense part of the Transact-SQL options.

Can anyone help, please?

Edit: I got a fresh install of SSMS2014 and am fine now, but in case anyone can answer this, it would be a handy resource for others.

Comment: I get this too, so annoying, so I'm moving towards not using single letters for table alias. I also get this many times when using the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER()` when I type `partition by` I get an auto-complete of something like `PARTITION_BY_FRAGMENT` or something like that.

Comment: you can try to use [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/). It has it's own IntelliSense